# Custom post types support in WordLift

Tags: wordpress, semantics, semantic-markup, wordlift

I am using the WordLift plugin for WordPress and I'd like to add support for Semantic SEO for other custom post types in my web site. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a filter you can use to add the custom post types: `wl_valid_entity_post_types`.

The filter takes an array with the supported post types (by default `post`, `page` and `entity`). You can add custom post types to the array and return it, e.g.:

`add_filter('wl_valid_entity_post_types', function ($post_types) {
  $post_types[] = 'gallery';
  return $post_types;
});`

For reference [add a WordPress filter to allow customers to extend the post types that can be turned into entities](https://github.com/insideout10/wordlift-plugin/issues/625) on GitHub.