# Custom taxonomy support in WordLift

Tags: wordpress, semantics, semantic-markup, wordlift

I am using the WordLift plugin for WordPress. I have created a custom taxonomy and I'd like to make it become a Wordlift entity. Is there a way to achieve it?

I've seen this answer for custom post types.
[Custom post types support in WordLift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011300/custom-post-types-support-in-wordlift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently working on an autocomplete select to use in the taxonomy terms edit screen that would allow you to select an entity from the Vocabulary, thus mapping a taxonomy term to an entity.

Initially I will use this to generate a JSON-LD for the taxonomy term and to provide extensible semantic tagging of posts (e.g. for a `LodgingBusiness` entity type which has an `amenityFeature` mapped to the taxonomy term, this would allow me to bind the `amenityFeature` to well-known knowledge graphs such as DBpedia and Wikidata).

In a later stage the entity page could extend the taxonomy term page and provide automatic suggestion for taxonomy terms when the entity is discovered in texts.

What is your aim exactly, it's would be useful to shape the next releases.

PS: WordLift CTO here.

Comment: Great! it looks exactly what I need. When do you plan to release this feature?

Comment: The first part, i.e. autocomplete select + JSON-LD, I think in a couple of weeks.